# iOS Storyboard - Custom Outlet from a ViewController to another?

Tags: ios, storyboard, iboutlet

I am trying to implement something similar to AplitView where you can hace separate scenes in storyboard and connect a viewController to another one as an outlet. Is this possible?

```
@Interface MenuNavigationController : UINavigationController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOUtlet MenuViewcontroller *menuViewController;

@end
```

In interfaceBuilder I want to drag and drop, and assign another viewController to my outlet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking child view controllers to a parent view controller within storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198698/linking-child-view-controllers-to-a-parent-view-controller-within-storyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode won't allow you to make connections between different scenes in a storyboard. It does allow such connections for the container view controllers that it knows about, like UISplitViewController, but not for your own. See [Linking child view controllers to a parent view controller within storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8198698/643383) for some useful ideas on this topic.