# How to go form one view to storyboard programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to connect with xib button to storyboard in iPhone? I have one project that every think contain storyboard I want to add this project to viewcontroller xib project, Now how to connect that xib button to storyboard programmatically. How to go form 1 view to storyboard view controller? How to connect that view controller button to story board?

Comment: i want to go from 1 view to storyboard view controller.how to connect that view controller button to story board.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198698/linking-child-view-controllers-to-a-parent-view-controller-within-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you have not create a Segue for your viewcontroller in storyboard, then you need to get the viewController from storyboard with you view identifier & need to apply pushViewController on action/event.

Example:

@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"   = Storyboard file name
@"TabBarCntrl"             = View controller identifier name

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarCntrl"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```