# Using Interface Builder and storyboards to build relationships between controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Is there a way to use Interface Builder on a storyboard to establish relationships between controllers. e.g. similar to the way UITabBarController allows you to click-drag connections to other UIViewControllers in the storyboard to build up the viewControllers relationship?

i.e. when you click-drag from UITabBarController to another UIViewController a popup gives you the option to choose "Relationships - viewControllers". It then draws and maintains the line between the controllers on the storyboard. I want to be able to do the same thing for my own custom controllers.

Comment: Of course you can do this. Just add a button to your first viewController. Control-Drag from your button to the secondViewController and u'll get the list. Choose Modal if you want to push the secondViewController on top of your First one.

Comment: Dani, you might want to reread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All evidence seems to point to the fact that this is not possible to do, at least in versions of XCode up to 4 and iOS versions up to 5. Will update if I discover this changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried, however it's looking bleak:

[How to create custom view controller container using storyboard in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122431/996768)

is a start (see the source code posted in the comments) but it's a work around - you don't get the relationship segues, however you do get Custom UIViewController containment.

I just thought it'd be prettier... Maybe iOS 8 will include this